# Why does zmq pack several messages to one TCP frame?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, zeromq

I send messages using `ZMQ_PUSH` socket with `ZMQ_DONTWAIT` flag. Each message separated by 300ms (so I seriously doubt, that my thread scheduling is so off). However from time to time several (up to 7 so far) messages are packed to the same TCP frame yet I don't see any retransmissions or reconnections in tcpdump.

Why is it happening? And how can I determine when my message would be sent?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm it is also wrong to assume one message per frame for tcp in general since it is connection-based protocol, not message-based

Comment: well but I guess I can assume at least 1 TCP frame per 2.1s

Comment: My best guess is a bug in ZMQ, wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol, there are no frames/packets/messages on the application level. Any number of `send()` calls can correspond to any number of `recv()` calls, and you can't assume anything more than that your data is transferred reliably and in the order you sent it. TCP generally doesn't guarantee any bounded transmission time, so if the underlying connection happens to be slow and/or unreliable, it can take quite some time until your data arrives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Q** : *"And how can I determine when my message would be sent?"*

You have zero-chance to know when a message, dispatched to be sent, would finally get down to the wire-level.

This is a property of the concept, not a bug. It was explicitly explained in the documentation, since the API v2.0+ ( and will most probably remain so forever ). It is fair to add that some insight into the `zmq_context`-instance's  internalities might be derived from a `socket_monitor` available  in the more recent API versions.